# Div with text wont stay centered

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple image gallery. Above the images I name the place where the pictures were taken, but the second and every another row has issues - div with the name is being pushed to the right instead of staying centered. Here is how it looks: http://prntscr.com/fg10u4

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);
.locationName {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="locations">

  <div class="locationName">
    City
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously the code is doubled inside the "row" div.

Comment: The problem doesn't show up in the code you provided. Try supplying a real [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a full 12 column grid to the `locationName` class so that it takes up the whole row and force a break between the other columns. As you currently have it, it is trying to be placed inline, which is after the longest image.

```
<div class="row" id="locations">

  <div class="col-xs-12 locationName">
    City
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Verefied. I use to have this issue. "col" has margins and paddings, and this is the reason you do not have the title "exactly" centered.

Comment: Well, the simplest solution, that I refused to even try (im that stupid) worked. Thank you for saving a lot of my time.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Its all about experimenting, take your time :)

Answer (score 2):

i saw your issue. actually there is a conflict with the boxes height. to quickly fix this you can increase your thumbs height equal. or you can see the example  code below.

```
    <div class="row" id="locations">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 locationName">City</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="2.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="1.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="2.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 locationName"> City </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="2.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="1.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="2.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bring this below code out of `row` and that should go the way you want.

```
<div class="locationName">
    City
</div>
```

> You are facing this problem because you can see in the image(link) you
>   provided that the **middle image** has moved slightly down and hence
>   it affects the title of the ***next row*** everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a conflict with the bootstrap you are using. Try moving the title (City) before the div with class row.

```
<div class="locationName">
    City
</div>

<div class="row" id="locations">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        <div class="container" id="locations">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="locationName">
            City
        </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use center tag like this

```html
<div class="row" id="locations">
    <center>
        ....
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element was deprecated in 1998. There's no reason to use it this century.